# Как сделать компонент, который будет полностью копировать свойства children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

У меня есть компонент, который проверяет права. Выглядит он следующим образом(для примера, упростил логику его работы):

```
const Access = ({allow, children}) => {
  return allow ? <>{children}</> : null
}
```

Этот компонент оборачивает компонент, который будет отображаться в зависимости от наличия права.
Примерно так:

```
return (
  <TabPanel>
    <Access allow={false}>
      <TabItem dataIndex={1}>
        <p>Первый таб</p>
      </TabItem>
    </Access>
      <TabItemdataIndex={2}>
        <p>Второй таб</p>
      </TabItem>
  </TabPanel>
)
```

Компонент `TabItem`  возвращает `JSX`.

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы компонент проверки прав `Acceess` "прикидывался" компонентом `TabItem` . То есть полностью передавал пропсы через себя и отвечал только за то, нужно рендерить компонент или нет.

Нужно это для того, чтобы в компоненте `TabPanel` я через пропс `children` получил доступ к `TabItem`, а именно к пропсам этого компонента.

Ко второму табу я могу обратиться таким образом, а вот к первому - нет.
Для наглядности прикреплю скрины:

1. Скрин из плагина ReactDevTools. Таким образом выглядит структура табов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Какие пропсы должны попадать в `TabItem`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Какие пропсы есть, при условие, что `TabItem` обернут в `Access`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Собственно пропсы, которые попадают в сам `Access`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Одной из попыток решения было, скопировать все пропсы, которые приходят в `Access`, через `React.cloneElement()`, следующим образом:

```
const Access = ({allow, children, ...restProps}) => {
  return allow ? React.cloneElement(children, restProps) : null
}
```

Но `children` у `Access` так и остался не тронутым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже совсем запутался. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Для начала имеет смысл сделать некий тестовый пример. Так смысл задуманного будет более понятным. На примере можно будет показывать некие примеры реализации.

Comment: Если обёртка не обязательна, то можно создать кастомный хук, который будет возвращать можно показывать или нет. А потом во всех нужных компонентах использовать этот хук и в звависимости от ответа решать показывать компонент или нет

Comment: Вообще не понятно зачем тут хук или компонент обертка, по сути тут просто условный рендеринг

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в компоненте access проверка на права, в примере логику я упростил. Был сделан в виде компонента, чтобы было удобно использовать, а не обращаться постоянно к функции проверки. У вас есть какие-нибудь мысли по этому поводу, может подскажите направления для "думания"?

Comment: @EzioMercer, да, можно, не спорю. Но куда деваться если в одном компоненте может проверяться несколько прав. Что тогда делать? Добавлять кучу хуков?

Comment: @DaniilLoban Да, вы правы, если права проверяются по-простому. Если сложная логика, то лучше выносить

Comment: @SaNFeeD нет, вам нужен один хук, который вам отправит объект вида `{isAdmin: false, isModerator: false, isSimpleUser: true}` и дальше достаёте нужный вам ключ

Comment: для сложной логики можно усложнить структуру но не код, смотря что Вы имеете в виду под сложной логикой

Comment: честно говоря, насколько я понимаю вопрос напрямую связан с безопасностью, поэтому я бы тут не спешил с хуками и прочими штуками — большая часть такого легко ломается

Comment: @EzioMercer, в приложении над которым я работаю список из 160 прав. Как-то накладно с хуками получатся....

Comment: @DaniilLoban. под сложной логикой я имею в виду работу с api, а именно запрос прав, мапинг прав, после чего запрос на их наличие.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Под сложной логикой я имею ввиду всё что НЕ простая однострочная проверка. Т.е. если в каждом компоненте нужно вычислять права хоть как-то (например каждый раз чтобы узнать есть ли права админа мы смотрим на права модератора и редактора `isAdmin = isModerator && isEditor`), то я предлагаю это ввнести. Я не очень понял как хуки ломаются. Буду рад если более детально об этом расскажете

Comment: @SaNFeeD А вы все 160 прав за один запрос получаете или каждый из 160 нужно отдельно запрашивать?

Comment: @EzioMercer. В одном запросе все

Comment: Тогда вам нужен не кастомный хук, а `createContext` и `useContext` или `Redux/RTK`. Запрашиваете права, создаёте удобный объект/словарь и дальше везде достаёте из этого объекта нужный ключ и в зависимости от его значения и рисуете то что вам нужно